# Ignoring notification with

Tags: android, notifications

Edit: It's fixed even though my code isn't perfect.  I forgot to register this BroadCastReceiver in my Android Manifest file.  *Face Palm*.

---

I'm having trouble getting my notification to work.  It would help if I get some meaningful error message but I have no idea how to debug this.

Here's the code of the broadcast receiver:

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class ThisDoesNotWork extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private Intent myIntent;
    private PendingIntent myPending;
    private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private final CharSequence text1 = "Text1";
    private final CharSequence text2 = "Text2!";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        myPending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, myIntent,
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Notification.Builder myNote = new Notification.Builder(context).setTicker(
                "Take a Selfie!")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(text1)
                .setContentText(text2)
                .setContentIntent(myPending);
        NotificationManager mNotify = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Log.i("Receiver", "Notification created.");
        mNotify.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID,myNote.getNotification());
        Log.i("Receiver", "Notification sent.");
    }

}
```

My program compiles but this notification gets ignored.

The error message I get is: Ignoring notification with icon==0; Notification(contentView =null vibrate=null...

Can anyone bring me 1 step closer to a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Per the [required notification contents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Required), you must include:

> - A small icon, set by [setSmallIcon()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int))
> - A title, set by [setContentTitle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContentTitle(java.lang.CharSequence))
> - Detail text, set by [setContentText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContentText(java.lang.CharSequence))

It appears you are missing the content title, causing your notification to get ignored.

Comment: Thanks...  I actually forgot to register the BroadCastReceiver..  this is only my 2nd Android program.